# typedef puzzled in c

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bitfield manipulation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044654/bitfield-manipulation-in-c)

I saw some c codes, typedef a struct, like

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned a:1;
    unsigned b:1;
    unsigned c:1;
    unsigned rest:13;

} Interface_type;
```

what dose `unsigned a:1;` mean?

Comment: It's called a bit-field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unsigned a:1
```

Defines a bit field that only occupies 1 bit.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: very thanks...I never use bit field...if bit fied better than bit mask? I think it will have problem when porting maybe？

Comment: I'm not sure about porting it - I guess the things that could go wrong would depend on the compiler for that target platform.

Comment: bitfields are horrible for porting. The standard does specify the layout so it is compiler specific. Really should stay away from them and uses mask for portability.

Comment: @James, yes, I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Signed variables, such as signed integers will allow you to represent numbers both in the positive and negative ranges.

Unsigned variables, such as unsigned integers, will only allow you to represent numbers in the positive

Comment: thank, i know signed or unsigned, i means what does `int a:1;` mean, the colon

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it specifies the size of the integer bit field..