# Bit Field of a specific size and order

Tags: c, sizeof, bit-fields

There are several times in C in which a type is guaranteed to be at LEAST a certain size, but not necessarily exactly that size (`sizeof(int)` can result in 2 or 4). However, I need to be absolutely certain of some sizes and memory locations. If I have a union such as below:

```
typedef union{
    struct{
        unsigned int a:1, b:1, c:1, d:1, e:1, f:1, g:1, h:1;
    };   
    unsigned int val:8;
} foo;
```

Is it absolutely guaranteed that the value of `val` is 8 bits long? Moreover, is it guaranteed that `a` is the most significant bit of `val`, and `b` is the second-most significant bit? I wish to do something like this:

```
foo performLogicalNOT(foo x){
    foo product;
    product.val = ~x.val;
    return product;
}
```

And thus with an input of specific flags, return a union with exactly the opposite flags (`11001100 -> 00110011`). The actual functions are more complex, and require that the size of `val` be exactly 8. I also want to perform AND and OR in the same manner, so it is crucial that each `a` and `b` value be where I expect them to be and the size I expect them to be.

Comment: [Bit fields are not portable and C doesn't guarantee about the ordering of the fields within the machine word](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1044689/183120).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the bits would be packed are not standard and pretty much implementation defined. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6044223/2682200).

Instead of relying on Union, it is better to use bitmask to derive the values. For the above example, `char foo` can be used. All operations (like ~) would be done on foo only. To get or set the bit specific values, appropriate bitmask can be used.

```
#define BITMASK_A  0x80
#define BITMASK_B  0x40
```

and so on..

To get the value of 'a' bit, use:

```
foo & BITMASK_A
```

To set the bit to 1, use:

```
foo | BITMASK_A
```

To reset the bit to 0, use:

```
foo & (~BITMASK_A)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. You may have just saved my senior project from what could have been a nasty bug. I will return to bitmasks. Is it correct, however, to assume that `a` is exactly 1 bit, or is that also implementation to specific?