# How to handle irregular bit sizes

Tags: c++

I am working on a project that contains variables of varying different bit sizes from a binary file. For example one line of the file (in hex) may look like "FF C0 AA 00 FE". From this line, for example, the information I need is 4 bits, 7 bits, 11 bits, 8 bits etc. 
The problem I am having is some of the numbers extracted will be signed and others will be unsigned (4 and 7 bits may be signed, 11 and 8 bits unsigned).

I was originally extracting by masking and shifting the Hex values to obtain a c++ char/short/int of 4, 7, 11, 8 bits. However if I look at the 4 bit in binary it would show up as 00001011. This number should be a negative based off the leading 1 (should only be the 4 bits 1011), but C++ recognizes it as positive since it is looking at all 8 bits.

Another example for clarification, I might extract 11 bits from the file to be (11100101101) but in c++ short format it appears as (0000011100101101), should be signed based of leading 1 in the 11 bits.

I was wondering what an ideal way to handle this would be. I was considering making a bit/byte class, the only problem is with the varying bit sizes (4,7,11,8).

Thanks, hopefully it makes sense. I am fairly new to binary in C++, so there may be a built in function I havent seen.

Comment: "FF C0 AA 00 FE" is a sequence of 4bit, 7bit, 11bit, 8bit,...data?

Comment: What about using a [bitfield](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) structure? Or a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) seems also useful for your case.

Comment: If FF C0 AA 00 FE is from the file, in binary it appears as (11111111 1100000 10101010...) then I need to take the first 4 bits as one number, so 1111. Then the next number is 7 bits and it would 1111110 (4 bits from FF, 4 from C0), 11 bits would be 00000101010, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume you can already extract the bits you desire by shifting and masking and or-ing together different pieces, and the problem is just to handle the sign bit.

```
int make_signed(int value, int bits)
{
    if (value & (1 << (bits - 1)))
        value |= -1 & ~((1 << bits) - 1);
    return value;
}
```

This starts by testing what would be the sign bit in your n-bit number. If it's set, the upper bits of the `int` are also set by starting with a value of `-1` (all bits set in two's complement) and masking off the bottom significant bits.

Comment: +1, but you can quite simply just shift twice to get sign extension (assuming a signed type for `value`): `value = value << (bits - 1) >> (bits - 1)`. EDIT: Actually, scratch that, that would only work in environments where the right-shift is an arithmetic one, which is implementation specific.

Comment: @Cameron thanks for pointing out that I missed something very important. I'm sticking with my original formula with one tiny mod.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Couldn't he just reset the sign bit and multiply the value by -1?

Comment: @cassiorenan No, because it wouldn't be the same value. For example the 4-bit sequence `1011` should be -5, not -3.

Comment: Of course. I was thinking completely wrong. More like multiply by -1, clear all "overflowing" MSB bits, multiply by -1.

Comment: Thanks Mark, rather simple implementation (if you know what you are doing) that handles my problem

Answer (score 1):

This has been done for you - see [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) - Just have an array of them

Comment: std::bitset does not address the users's needs.  He is trying to store small integers, not collections of bits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve your purpose for the two examples given in your question:

```
char src = 0x0B;              // 00001011
char dst = (char)(src<<4)>>4; // 11111011

short src = 0x072D;             // 0000011100101101
short dst = (short)(src<<5)>>5; // 1111111100101101
```

---

In general, you can implement a function for `signed` values and a function for `unsigned` values:

```
#include <limits.h>

signed int GetSignedVal(signed int val,int numOfBits)
{
    int shift = sizeof(val)*CHAR_BITS-numOfBits;
    return (val<<shift)>>shift;
}

unsigned int GetUnsignedVal(unsigned int val,int numOfBits)
{
    int shift = sizeof(val)*CHAR_BITS-numOfBits;
    return (val<<shift)>>shift;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a rarely-used feature in C/C++ called a bit field that addresses your problem.

```
    struct HodgePodgge {
            bool oneBooleanBit:1;
            int fourBitsOfSignedInteger:4;
            unsigned int sixUnsignedIntegerBits:6;
    };
```

'sizeof(HodgePodge)' should be 2  (11 bits total fits in two bytes)

The compiler generates code to do the shifting, masking, and sign extensions for you.  This is a good thing because it does NOT guarantee the layout of the bits within HodgePodge.

[This link gives details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044654/bitfield-manipulation-in-c)

Bit fields have been there *forever* but nobody uses them.  Beware you may have to education your coworkers (or comment appropriately)