# How can I span bit field across a union?

Tags: c

Here is the structure I want:

```
typedef struct someip_header { 
    union { 
        uint32_t message_id;
        struct {
            uint16_t service_id; 
            uint8_t for_rpc : 1; 
            union {
                uint16_t method_id : 15;
                uint16_t event_id : 15;
            };
        };
    };
} someip_header_t;
```

(The reason is that if for_rpc is 1, then the last 15 bits mean event ID, otherwise they mean method ID)

But the size of this structure is 5 bytes (packed), I guess because the compiler won't put union unaligned. If I replace the inner union with just a `uint16_t val : 15`, the size gets back to 4 bytes as expected:

```
typedef struct someip_header { 
    union { 
        uint32_t message_id;
        struct {
            uint16_t service_id; 
            uint8_t for_rpc : 1; 
            uint16_t method_event_id : 15;
        };
    };
} someip_header_t;
```

Just wondering, is there a way to pack this? It's really only cosmetic, but still...

Comment: While not being really my favorite thing, here MISRA is right when prohibiting use of unions and bit fields. A changed compiler switch or a new compiler / target platform / tool chain and much more might break this code. For example, the alignment of the ``for_rpc`` might change from tool chain to tool chain. Instead of composing the header like this, it might be a better idea to do it with a serialization function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044654/bitfield-manipulation-in-c for more info. Further idea: Generate code from ASN.1.

Comment: In the first example, the size of the inner struct is at least 5 bytes. If you define members that take 5 bytes, then they cannot occupy less than 5 bytes.

Comment: @2501 the total number of bits was equal to 4 bytes (even).

Comment: @PawelVeselov Union is not a bit-field thus the remaining bits of `for_rpc` cannot be used for the bit-field inside the union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form the `union` at the byte level:

```
typedef struct someip_header { 
    union { 
        uint32_t message_id;
        struct {
            uint16_t service_id; 
            union {
                struct {
                    uint8_t for_rpc : 1; 
                    uint16_t method_id : 15;
                };
                struct {
                    uint8_t for_rpc_2 : 1; 
                    uint16_t event_id : 15;
                };
            };
        };
    };
} someip_header_t;
```

Comment: One can remove `for_rpc_2` and omit it all together, making it even cleaner, IMHO.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to literally remove `for_rpc_2`, as a name, making an anonymous 1 bit hole.

Comment: @PawelVeselov: Fair enough. I won't claim to have a great handle on C, only enough to get me where I need to go.